# Inside text editor my preview gallery images are in full size

Tags: gallery, thumbnails

As I described in the title in the edit post page and inside the editor when I submit a new gallery the thumbnails are in full size.

I suspect that this error caused when I unset the default "thumbnails" size in the functions.php but that was not last long and I recovered the thumbnail size.

What I want is the image size inside the gallery preview (in admin side) to be thumbnail (the default) not the full size. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I forgot the question!! I updated the text. Thanks